# idpiframe_initialization_failed in Google Sign In from Localhost

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth, google-signin, google-plus-signin

I'm trying to create a Google Sign In button by following [this link](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/). So far the account choose dialogue box is coming but after that I don't see any result in the console. Instead I'm getting this error at page load,

```
"idpiframe_initialization_failed", details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhos…itelist this origin for your project's client ID."
details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://localhost has not been whitelisted for client ID 386404527657-q4ss06np5g27dllq5ds7aif42udkh7e5.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
```

- I've set Javascript Origins *http://localhost* & *http://192.168.0.100:3000*
- I've set Redirect URI *http://localhost:8080/Callback* & *http://localhost:8080*

Here are the codes,

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta name="google-signin-scope" content="profile email">
    <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">
    <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="g-signin2" data-onsuccess="onSignIn" data-theme="dark"</div>
    <script>
      function onSignIn(googleUser) {
        // Useful data for your client-side scripts:
        var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
        console.log("ID: " + profile.getId()); // Don't send this directly to your server!
        console.log('Full Name: ' + profile.getName());
        console.log('Given Name: ' + profile.getGivenName());
        console.log('Family Name: ' + profile.getFamilyName());
        console.log("Image URL: " + profile.getImageUrl());
        console.log("Email: " + profile.getEmail());

        // The ID token you need to pass to your backend:
        var id_token = googleUser.getAuthResponse().id_token;
        console.log("ID Token: " + id_token);
      };
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I get the results in my console?

Comment: Did you use your client id???  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="YOUR_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com">

Comment: Yes. I just didn't put it here for security reason.

Comment: Try [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52584572/1485287). It requires www.localhost

Answer (score 89):

I was having this exact issue and [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45761277/4115031) worked for me.

In short: clear your browser cache.

In Chrome: Settings → Privacy and security → Clear browsing data → Cached images and files

Comment: Thanks, clearing the browser cache allowed auth to work in step 3 of the bigquery-maps-api sample.

Comment: Sometimes you remove cache, but for some reason it is not [fully] removed and you continue to see the problem thinking 'what the hell?'. Just check your site in Incognito Window in order to be sure that the problem is not with cache.

Comment: I want to add that if you are using an extension like Privacy Badger that blocks google cookies then nothing will work.

Answer (score 9):

The solution which worked for me was to whitelist the origin in the google developer console api for that application.

Answer (score 9):

Just clear your cache or open your URL in incognito mode. that it :).
your issue will get resolved.

Comment: In my experience, Google login generally doesn't work in Incognito mode.

Comment: It works as same as it works in the Normal Browser Window.

Comment: you cant use it in incognito since cookies aren't allowed

Answer (score 7):

For me it was Settings > Site Settings > Cookies > "Blocked thrid-party cookies" must have been unchecked.

Comment: More Info https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/troubleshooting#known_issues

Answer (score 6):

I experienced this error on several sites that offer Google Sign in. 
I had to "allow" accounts.google.com cookie in the "show cookies and other site data" for the site to make it work (after reloading the page).
Probably blocking 3rd party cookies in the browser was the root cause for first place,

Answer (score 6):

The documentation says not to overlook two critical steps ("As you go through the instructions, it's important that you not overlook these two critical steps: Enable the Analytics API Here's what worked for me:

1. **Enable the Analytics API**
2. **back to you credentials , delete previous OAuth 2.0**
3. **now create new OAuth with correct origins**

Comment: This worked for me! Clearing cache didn't.

Comment: This was the solution for me as well, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you are using '@abacritt/angularx-social-login' for social media login using Angular, the below fix worked for me. This issue happens for all the newly created Client IDs. This can be overcome by adding 'plugin_name' in the provider for Angular.

In app.module.ts, create an object which holds the 'plugin_name'.

```
const googleLoginOptions = {
  scope: 'profile email',
  plugin_name:'sample_login' //can be any name
};
```

And in  providers, pass the 'googleLoginOptions' object along with the google client ID.

```
@NgModule({
 declarations: [
    AppComponent
    ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    NgbModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    CommonModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SocialLoginModule
  ],
  schemas: [ CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA ],
  providers: [
        {
          provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
          useValue: {
            autoLogin: false,
            providers: [
              {
                id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
                provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
                  'YOUR GOOGLE CLIENT_ID', 
                   googleLoginOptions
                )
              }
            ],
            onError: (err) => {
              console.error(err);
            }
          } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
        }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Now, clear the browser cache and it should be working.
For the changes in app.component.ts you may refer to [@abacritt/angularx-social-login- documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@abacritt/angularx-social-login)

Please note, this solution only works for Angular applications which use the @abacritt/angularx-social-login NPM package.

Comment: This works on my Angular Application. Thanks a lot

Comment: +1 I'm not using angular but setting the plugin_name worked for me after trying clearing cache. Creating new credentials. Trying different browsers. Running on the live site.

Answer (score 0):

My solution wass to add `http://localhost:yourPort` and `https://localhost:yourPort`. Then just delete cache and browser data

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is that I've accidentally been typing out the address in field called "Authorized redirect URIs" instead of "Authorized JavaScript origins". Replace those two fields and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem i faced, after trying many things this is what worked for me:
Step 1: use gapi-script in the react project for that
**npm i gapi-script** 
Step 2: import it in the project 
**import { gapi } from "gapi-script";**
Step 3: write a useEffect function
***useEffect(() => {
const clientId =
"enter your client id here";
function start() {
gapi.client.init({
clientId: clientId,
scope: "",
});
}
gapi.load("client:auth2", start);
});*** 
Step 4:
this is it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried deleting the cache and browser but it did not work for me.
So I have a solution that helps me fix it.

1. Install gapi-script (https://www.npmjs.com/package/gapi-script).

   **`npm install --save gapi-script`**
2. Use it in component.

   ```
     import { loadGapiInsideDOM } from "gapi-script";
     ...
     useEffect(() => {
       (async () => {
         await loadGapiInsideDOM();
       })();
     });
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced this error many times and searched for a very long time for a solution,

for me the issue got solved after whitelising http://127.0.0.1:3000 to Authorized JavaScript origins and Authorized redirect URIs in google API

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was multiple domains, moreover subdomains. Deleting one and creating the new client id for other solved the issue.