# How to solve "idpiframe_initialization_failed" for localhost?

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-oauth

Here's my initialization code:

```
            function HandleGoogleApiLibrary() {
                // Load "client" & "auth2" libraries
                gapi.load('client:auth2', {
                    callback: function () {
                        // Initialize client & auth libraries
                        gapi.client.init({
                            apiKey: 'My API Key',
                            clientId: 'My Client ID',
                            scope: 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me'
                        }).then(
                            function (success) {
                                console.log("Yaaay");
                            },
                            function (error) {
                                console.log("Nope");
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                        );
                    },
                    onerror: function () {
                        // Failed to load libraries
                    }
                });
            }
```

Which gives me the following error message:

```
details: "Not a valid origin for the client: http://127.0.0.1 has not been whitelisted for client ID 388774754090-o7o913o81ldb2jcfu939cfu36kh9h0q6.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"
```

My app is not in production yet, so for development I'm using localhost. Thing is, on *every* stack overflow / reference I've found they've specified that on `Authorised JavaScript origins` and `Authorised redirect URIs` I must use `http://localhost` instead of `http://127.0.0.1`. If I do this, I get that error and a `Permission denied to generate login hint for target domain.` if I try to login.

If I use `http://127.0.0.1` on both, I get no `idpiframe_initialization_failed` on initialization, but get the same permission denied when I try to login.

It makes no sense, there's no other way to specify the localhost, and I just can't use the API.

Comment: it seems you have  enabled api restrictions (API key with HTTP referer restriction) in google api console, go to google developer console and add 127.0.0.1 to allowed domains or ip

Comment: Nope, I've checked. Under "Application restrictions" there are no restrictions (None). Also, on OAuth Consent Screen, in "Authorized Domains", I can't put either 127.0.0.1 or localhost, it says: Invalid domain: must be a top private domain.

Comment: can you also check ifthis is causing the issue

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/troubleshooting#third-party_cookies_and_data_blocked

Comment: Nope, not blocking cookies. I'm trying to use http://xip.io/.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/44488113/27614 - you may fix this problem by just re-adding a fresh set of OAuth credentials, with the same `http://localhost[:PORT]` you had before.

Answer (score 19):

In my case it was two-side problem.

1. Need to add origin to google console.

   How does origin look like? http://localhost
2. Clear cache.

   This sometimes does not work and you may start thinking that this is not a cache problem. Details below.

---

**1. How to add your origin to google console?**

- Go here: https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials
- Select a Project you need at the top.
- Find `OAuth 2.0 client IDs` and in this section select (or create) a client ID.
- In the opened window find the section `Restrictions -> Authorized JavaScript origins` and add either `http://localhost` or `http://localhost:8000` (specifying the port you need).

**2. Clear cache.**

If the step #1 did not solve the problem, you need to clear cache.

If you want to remove just `localhost` cache, in `Chrome` you can do it in the next way:

- Open Settings -> More tools -> Developer tools;
- Right click on Reload button -> Empty Cache and Hard Reload.

Sometimes cache clearing does not work. Just to be sure, that it is still a cache problem, open a browser using Incognito mode and check your site again.

Comment: Didn't work for me. And I've tried all the solutions presented in this page. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Just to save future readers, I've managed to authenticate from the localhost by typing exactly `http://www.localhost` on "Authorized Javascript Origins" in the Client ID creation (Credentials / Developer Console). Totally not obvious and anti-user, but neither `http://localhost` or `http://127.0.0.1` worked.

Comment: It's not working for me says "Invalid Origin: must end with a public top-level domain (such as .com or .org)."

Answer (score 0):

For me problem was solved by disabling AdBlocker

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue on Version 100.0.4896.127 (Official Build) snap (64-bit) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. Allowing third-party cookies under Settings -> Privacy and Security -> Cookies and other site data solved it. The moment I disabled the third party cookies, the issue was back. So, for my case at least, it seems the issue is third party cookies not enabled. Note that I had the URL of the application as http://localhost:some-port

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem i faced, after trying many things this is what worked for me:

- **Step 1:** use gapi-script in the react project for that

```
npm i gapi-script
```

- **Step 2:** import it in the project

```
import { gapi } from "gapi-script"
```

- **Step 3:** write a `useEffect` function

```js
useEffect(() => {
    const clientId =
      "enter your client id here";
    function start() {
      gapi.client.init({
        clientId: clientId,
        scope: "",
      });
    }
    gapi.load("client:auth2", start);
  });
```