# Having a trouble with Google OAuth2. Can't sign up with google

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-platform, localhost, google-developers-console

[Been facing this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xf2Is.png)
"You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
[How to sign in with google now if they have block client ID for new users](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3buIt.png)

Comment: What is the problem? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I've added the screenshot. Anyone who can come up with the soultion

Answer (score 8):

as google will deprecate their old sign in library
https://developers.googleblog.com/2021/08/gsi-jsweb-deprecation.html

you can now implement their new google service identity SDK https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web

or if you are using react, I made a small package https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google
it is using the new SDK

Comment: I have tried this library with new creds and it worked first try. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For angular developers,
a repository with an example of how to use the new google sign in:
https://github.com/ShemiNechmad/GoogleSignInAngular

Check the readme.md file for instructions.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just looking for the solution for older version of Angular.

Answer (score 2):

I was having this issue and solved it using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72392924/5068710)

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GoogleLogin, GoogleLogout } from 'react-google-login';
import env from 'react-dotenv';
import { gapi } from 'gapi- script';

function AuthPage() {  
  useEffect(() => {
    function start() {
      gapi.client.init({
        clientId: env.REACT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: 'email',
      });
    }

    gapi.load('client:auth2', start);
  }, []);


  // **you can access the token like this**
  // const accessToken = gapi.auth.getToken().access_token;
  // console.log(accessToken);

  const onSuccess = response => {
    console.log('SUCCESS', response);
  };
  const onFailure = response => {
    console.log('FAILED', response);
  };
  const onLogoutSuccess = () => {
    console.log('SUCESS LOG OUT');
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <GoogleLogin
        clientId={env.REACT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
        onSuccess={onSuccess}
        onFailure={onFailure}
      />
      <GoogleLogout
        clientId={env.REACT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
        onLogoutSuccess={onLogoutSuccess}
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default AuthPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced the same issue, like you.

This is how I solved it in my React Application. https://stackoverflow.com/a/72944782/15145736

it will solve the problem