# I got this issue when, I am trying to run this code (gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().signIn();) "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

Tags: reactjs, authentication, google-authentication, google-api-js-client, googleauthr

error: 'idpiframe_initialization_failed', details: 'You have created a new client application that use…i/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information.'}
details: "You have created a new client application that uses libraries for user authentication or authorization that will soon be deprecated. New clients must use the new libraries instead; existing clients must also migrate before these libraries are deprecated. See the [Migration Guide](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/guides/gis-migration) for more information."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed" [image]

Answer (score 17):

Gapi sign-in method will be deprecated by March 2023 and it will be not used.so you must go with the new method mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web)

Update: Also you can add plugin_name to your code to bypass error like this:

```js
window.gapi.client
        .init({
          clientId:'Your Client ID',
          scope: "email",
          plugin_name:'App Name that you used in google developer console API'
        })
```

Answer (score 5):

you can use [@react-oauth/google](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-oauth/google) it uses the new google service identity SDK

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The same error happens with react-google-login but @react-oauth/google works fine

Answer (score 4):

This is how I solved it in my React Application.

1. `npm i gapi-script`
2. in your auth or login file import it. `import { gapi } from "gapi-script";`
3. use this `useEffect` code in your file.

```js
 useEffect(() => {
    function start() {
      gapi.client.init({
        clientId: process.env.REACT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
        scope: 'email',
      });
    }

    gapi.load('client:auth2', start);
  }, []);
```

it will solve the problem

Answer (score 2):

check these blog
https://github.com/anthonyjgrove/react-google-login/issues/502

or try these

Here is what I am using.

First I have a general hook called useScript that can load any  tag into the HTML head and has a callback function for when the script fully loads:

```js
import { useEffect } from "react";

const useScript = (url, onload) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement("script");

    script.src = url;
    script.onload = onload;

    document.head.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
      document.head.removeChild(script);
    };
  }, [url, onload]);
};

export default useScript;
```

Then I have created a GoogleLogin component that loads Google's button.

```js
import { useRef } from "react";
import useScript from "hooks/useScript";

export default function GoogleLogin({
  onGoogleSignIn = () => {},
  text = "signin_with",
  // feel free to add more options here
}) {
  const googleSignInButton = useRef(null);

  useScript("https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client", () => {
    window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: process.env.REACT_APP_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      callback: onGoogleSignIn,
    });
    window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      googleSignInButton.current,
      { theme: "outline", size: "large", text, width: "250" } // customization attributes
    );
  });

  return <div className="test" ref={googleSignInButton}></div>;
}
```

Pretty straightforward!

Answer (score 0):

There are three step to resolved this issue

#### 1. Give google Login Options

```js
const googleLoginOptions = {
  scope: 'profile email',
  plugin_name:'sample_login' 
};
```

#### 2. Import SocialLoginModule into imports array

```js
imports:[SocialLoginModule]
```

#### 3. step register into provider like that

```js
providers: [
    {
      provide: 'SocialAuthServiceConfig',
      useValue: {
        autoLogin: false,
        providers: [
          {
            id: GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
            provider: new GoogleLoginProvider(
              CLIENT_ID,
              googleLoginOptions
            )
          }
        
        ],
        onError: (err) => {
          console.error(err);
        }
      } as SocialAuthServiceConfig,
    }
```