# How to make google signin work on localhost

Tags: google-signin

Google sign-in doesn't work. I tried cleaning the cache as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46472945/idpiframe-initialization-failed-in-google-sign-in-from-localhost).
I even tried using a completely different web browser but it still does not work.

[image: localhost 5000 is not a valid domain image]

I made sure to mark the domain as authorized but it still does not want to work.

[image: the domain is marked as authorized]

When pressing the login button, The popup shows just fine. There is no error whatsoever, but once I choose my email account, the loading spinner shows and the popup closes after some time.

Please someone help me.

[image: Loading spinner]

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately there is no native solution but you can use a third-party service like [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) to get the job done. And here is a very good tutorial how to achieve that. [Local Auth test with ngrock](https://medium.com/bigcommerce-developer-blog/how-to-test-app-authentication-locally-with-ngrok-149150bfe4cf)

Comment: Hello. I thought it would work on localhost because I saw it written somewhere in their docs. Thank you for your response, it really helps. I will be using ngrok.

Comment: Thanks Daniel if you could please vote on my answer I would really appreciate 

Answer (score -3):

Try adding **http://localhost** as well to the list of authorized Javascript origins.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).